# How to do Dataflow aggregation and join in python with composite keys

Tags: python, join, pipeline, composite-key, dataflow

I have following two PCollections as inputs:

First PCollection is a list of ad impressions with, say, a few attributes such as the following:

```
advertiser_id, campaign_id, ad_id, event_date
```

Second PCollection is a list of rows with the following:

```
advertiser_id, campaign_id, ad_id, ad_name, click_through_url, ad_type
```

I'd like to aggregate the ad impressions over the composite key of (advertiser_id, campaign_id, ad_id, event_date) and join with the second PCollection. The result PCollection should be as follows:

```
advertiser_id, campaign_id, ad_id, event_date,ad_name, click_through_url, ad_type,impressions
```

All the examples I could find with GroupByKey or CoGroupByKey was dealing with single-attribute keys. I'm new to Dataflow and python so any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out so want to post here in case anyone has similar need. The way to do it is to convert the data to a key-value pair with the key defined by a class with all the attributes except for impressions and impressions as value. Then perform a CombinePerKey(sum) transform.